How to adjust the resolution of the R windowing system, e.g., view(), plot()
Not using Rstudio, how do I change the resolution of the interactive windowing system (X11, etc)? I have changed to a new computer and the font size of the output of View() is tiny, and all plots font sizes are also tiny. Saving plots using ggsave results in the correct resolution and font sizes.
Running plot(1:10, main = "Example") results in an error:
Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) : 
  X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 16 could not be loaded

For the View problem I have used alternative like DT::datatable and kableExtra::kbl which are both great but not as fast as View().
I have also played around with grDevices::X11.options() but found no solution.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Edit: Some more info
sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Running under: Fedora Linux 41 (Workstation Edition)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: FlexiBLAS OPENBLAS-OPENMP;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Zurich
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DT_0.33            kableExtra_1.4.0   lubridate_1.9.3   
 [4] rio_1.2.3          RColorBrewer_1.1-3 ggrepel_0.9.6     
 [7] colorspace_2.1-1   viridis_0.6.5      viridisLite_0.4.2 
[10] cowplot_1.1.3      ggplot2_3.5.1      dplyr_1.1.4       
[13] tidyr_1.3.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] sass_0.4.9        utf8_1.2.4        generics_0.1.3   
 [4] xml2_1.3.6        tcltk_4.4.2       stringi_1.8.4    
 [7] digest_0.6.37     magrittr_2.0.3    evaluate_1.0.1   
[10] timechange_0.3.0  fastmap_1.2.0     cellranger_1.1.0 
[13] R.oo_1.27.0       jsonlite_1.8.9    R.utils_2.12.3   
[16] gridExtra_2.3     purrr_1.0.2       fansi_1.0.6      
[19] crosstalk_1.2.1   scales_1.3.0      jquerylib_0.1.4  
[22] cli_3.6.3         crayon_1.5.3      rlang_1.1.4      
[25] R.methodsS3_1.8.2 munsell_0.5.1     yaml_2.3.10      
[28] cachem_1.1.0      withr_3.0.2       tools_4.4.2      
[31] vctrs_0.6.5       R6_2.5.1          lifecycle_1.0.4  
[34] stringr_1.5.1     htmlwidgets_1.6.4 pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[37] bslib_0.8.0       pillar_1.9.0      gtable_0.3.6     
[40] data.table_1.16.2 glue_1.8.0        Rcpp_1.0.13-1    
[43] systemfonts_1.1.0 xfun_0.49         tibble_3.2.1     
[46] tidyselect_1.2.1  rstudioapi_0.17.1 knitr_1.49       
[49] farver_2.1.2      htmltools_0.5.8.1 labeling_0.4.3   
[52] svglite_2.1.3     rmarkdown_2.29    compiler_4.4.2   
[55] readxl_1.4.3     
> capabilities("X11")
 X11 
TRUE 
> names(X11Fonts())
[1] "serif"        "sans"         "mono"         "Times"       
[5] "Helvetica"    "CyrTimes"     "CyrHelvetica" "Arial"       
[9] "Mincho"      

